# List loop in python

Tags: python, list, loops

I'd like to edit some elements in python's list inside a loop. How can I make a proper loop for this? This code doesn't work:

```
for i in X:
  i=(i-C1)/C2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
X = [(i-C1)/C2 for i in X]
```

And a minor point, the [Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) recommends using all lower case for your variable names, e.g.:

```
x = [(i-c1)/c2 for i in x]
```

Capital letters are usually used to start class names (and all-capitals denotes a constant).

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
X=[(i-C1)/C2 for i in X]
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that although the following is possible it may not be recommended:

```
for i,v in enumerate(X):
  X[i]=(v-C1)/C2
```

Comment: People don't recommend editing a data structure while iterating through it, although I don't see the problem in this case.

Comment: @robert, you shouldn't add or remove elements while iterating. Replacing items is ok

Comment: This is the way to do it if you need to include other statements in the loop, or perhaps if the formula is more complicated

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
X = [(y - C1) / C2 for y in X]
```

This will not modify your list, but create a new list based on the change you wanted to do and assign it back to X.

Answer (score 1):

using X[:] is better than X, as it allows splice assignment:

```
X[:] = [(y - C1) / C2 for y in X]
```

if you wanted to loop through, I would recommend using `enumerate(X)`.

e.g.

```
for i,y in enumerate(X):
    X[i] = (y - C1) / C2
```

Here i is assigned the position in the array (i = 0..len(X)-1) and y is the value of X[i].

look up enumerate if you're interested.

Of course you must be careful if you edit a list (or any data structure) while iterating through it in case you change values before they have been iterated. e.g:

```
x = [1,2,3]

for i,y in enumerate(x):
    x[-1] = 99
    print(i,y)

>>>
0 1
1 2
2 99
```

notice you get "2 99" instead of "2 3"

Comment: The slice assignment is a good way to save memory if you use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension `X[:] = ((y - C1) / C2 for y in X)`